# How to have multiple left outer join possibilities

Tags: sql

In this query, we have left outer join to the formulary table.

Now  I learnt that, some records not in this table based on NDC 
but ARE in based on a SEQNO.

SO we have this alternative join if you will. how to code that
if the join on ndc is not found, let's join on SEQNO = SEQ_NO

```
"SELECT distinct f.FACILITY_NAME, ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED], [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], " +
                    " case when COST > 0 then (COST / DAYSUPPLY) * 30 else 0 end [30DayCost] , [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER], [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS] , f.FACILITY_ID " +
                    " FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC]   Left Outer Join PBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI  Where [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5) AND SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null AND [TIER] <> 'T1'  " +
                    sqlWhere + " AND f.FACILITY_ID IN (" + selected + ")";
```

Comment: Use UNION. There is nothing like alternative join.

Comment: ok but couldn't i have another left outer join? I suppose not. How to code for the union for seqno i am not familiar with Union so much.

Comment: You could have an another join, but you cant get information from it.

Comment: ok but the seq_no only comes into play when there is no NDC. main processing will be according to NDC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use union, you are going to get the same result.

```
        "SELECT distinct f.FACILITY_NAME, ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, 
    [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED], 
    [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], 
    [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], " 
    + " case when COST > 0 then (COST / DAYSUPPLY) * 30 else 0 end [30DayCost] ,
     [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER], 
    [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS] , f.FACILITY_ID "
    +" FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON A.[NDC] = B.[NDC]   Left Outer Join PBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI  Where [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5) AND SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null AND [TIER] <> 'T1'  " 
    + sqlWhere + " AND f.FACILITY_ID IN (" + selected + ")" 

+
"UNION 
SELECT distinct f.FACILITY_NAME, ID_KEY, [BATCH] AS column1, 
    [IMPORTDATE], [DATEBILLED], [RX], [DATEDISPENSED], 
    [DAYSUPPLY], [PAYTYPE], [NPI], [PHYSICIAN], [COST], 
    [QUANTITY], [MEDICATION], A.[NDC], " 
    + " case when COST > 0 then (COST / DAYSUPPLY) * 30 else 0 end [30DayCost] ,
     [PATIENTNAME], [ROUTEOFADMIN], [INVOICECAT], [COPAY], [BRAND], [TIER], 
    [SKILLLEVEL], [STAT] STATUS, [LASTTASKDATE],SEQNO,B.[SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS] , f.FACILITY_ID "
    +" FROM [PBM].[T_CHARGES] A LEFT OUTER JOIN [OGEN].[NDC_M_FORMULARY] B ON SEQNO = SEQ_NO Left Outer Join PBM.FACILITY f on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI  Where [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5) AND SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null AND [TIER] <> 'T1'  " 
    + sqlWhere + " AND f.FACILITY_ID IN (" + selected + ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do with an additional join to the formulary table, just with a different alias.  Also, since you had and "AND B.SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null" at the WHERE clause, that was FORCING the query to an INNER JOIN.  I have moved that to the left-join component.  Immediately under that, I added a secondary left-join but using the alias "BySEQNO" (with similar subst_inst not null but by its alias).

For the column being retrieved, I applied a COALESCE() basically saying if the value is null in the "B." alias, grab the value from the "BySEQNO" alias.

As for the "sqlwhere" and "selected" values you are building in the string, I have no idea on that impact.

Finally, for clarity in querying, you should always apply table.column (or at least alias.column) for readability as if a column is unique to only one table, the engine will know and figure it out, but for those trying to help, or read after you, it won't be as obvious the column's origin.

```
SELECT distinct 
      f.FACILITY_NAME, 
      ID_KEY, 
      BATCH AS column1, 
      IMPORTDATE, 
      DATEBILLED, 
      RX, 
      DATEDISPENSED, 
      DAYSUPPLY, 
      PAYTYPE, 
      NPI, 
      PHYSICIAN, 
      COST, 
      QUANTITY, 
      MEDICATION, 
      A.NDC,
      case when COST > 0 
         then (COST / DAYSUPPLY) * 30 
         else 0 end [30DayCost], 
      PATIENTNAME, 
      ROUTEOFADMIN, 
      INVOICECAT, 
      COPAY, 
      BRAND, 
      TIER, 
      SKILLLEVEL, 
      [STAT] STATUS, 
      LASTTASKDATE,
      SEQNO,
      COALESCE( B.SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS, BySEQNO.SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS ) SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS,
      f.FACILITY_ID 
   FROM 
      PBM.T_CHARGES A 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN OGEN.NDC_M_FORMULARY B 
            ON A.NDC = B.NDC
            AND B.SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN OGEN.NDC_M_FORMULARY BySEQNO
            ON A.SEQNO = BySEQNO.SEQ_No
            AND BySEQNO.SUBST_INSTRUCTIONS is not null 
         Left Outer Join PBM.FACILITY f 
            on A.FACILITYNPI = f.FACILITY_NPI  
   Where 
          [STAT] not in (3, 4, 5) 
      AND TIER <> 'T1'  
      sqlWhere 
      AND f.FACILITY_ID IN (" + selected + ")";
```